# Calculate the unit normal vectors to the both sides of a plane

Tags: vector-spaces

Calculate the unit normal vectors to the both sides of a plane passing through three points with coordinates (1,0,1), (1,1,-1) and(-1,1,1).

My answer is [$\sqrt{6}/6 , \sqrt{6}/3 , \sqrt{6}/6$] and for the other side I just have to multiply by -1 which gives [$-\sqrt{6}/6 , -\sqrt{6}/3 , -\sqrt{6}/6$]

I would like to check whether I'm correct and for calculating the normal, does it matter which coordinate i choose to form the vectors??

Comment: this seems to be correct. To check, the easiest way is to take to vectors tangent to the plane and calcuale the scalar product with your normal vector. I'm not sure what you mean with your last question.

Comment: Lets say A=(1,0,1), B=(1,1,−1), C=(−1,1,1).
The vectors I used are CA and CB. But once I change the vector to BA and BC I got a different normal. So which set of vectors should I use to get the right normal?

Comment: Then you miscalculated. You can use any pair of linear independent vectors lying in that plane and should arrive at the same normal, up to length an sign of course.

Answer (score -1):

Call $A=(1,0,1)$, $B=(1,1,-1)$, $C=(-1,1,1)$.

Each of the two vectors you found give $0$ in scalar product with $A-B$, $B-C$ (and $C-A$) and the modules of those vectors are $1$ in both cases (if you call the first $\vec{v}$, the second is $-\vec{v}$).

Without pen and paper next to me, I'd say you're right: you found two unit vectors, $\pm\vec{v}$, normal to the plane thru $A,B,C$.

P.S.: Changing system of coordinates may alter single components but NOT modules and orthogonality, which are indeed **invariants**.